# SCCM Deploying Win7 Enterprise select language during OSD

Tags: windows-7, sccm, operating-system, sccm-2012, sccm-2012-r2

I am attempting to implement more automation and less manual click through  with our SCCM OSD.

Our currently running Tasksequence works nearly perfect for us, but we still have to manually choose the language during the Installation since we are using win7 Enterprise.

I searched around for an answer and found out that you can create Answer Files and include them into your Tasksequence.

When I do this am I still going to be asked which language to choose or will it read the Answer File and run without user interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can use an answer file to specify international settings**

To configure international settings regarding your Windows 7 Enterprise automated installation by referring to this [**Microsoft Technet article.**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766181(v=ws.10).aspx)

You will need the appropriate language pack that you intend to install.  As well, you can add language packs to the Operating System if it is not apart of the build you plan on installing.  These components will be apart of your answer file.  To create an answer file, refer to [**this article.**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709633(v=ws.10).aspx)  You will also be required to use [**Windows SIM (System Image Manager)**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824929.aspx) as component of the overall solution of automating your installations.